# Is it legit to turn a well-received comment I made on an answer into a separate answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

About a week ago, I made [the following comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/70987/is-it-insulting-to-call-a-full-professor-dr-firstname-lastname-in-a-non-academi/70995#comment172409_70995) on an answer in Academia.SE  (although this situation has popped up in other settings):

> Note: take care to send the mails in such a way that an accidental reply-all doesn't bother the other people on the mailing list.

This comment was related to the answer and I intended it as more of a "if you do this, don't forget to do X" remark, but it appeared well-received, and some people even expressed that they wanted to bounty it, but couldn't because it was a comment.

Would it be considered in poor taste or in violation of a Stack Exchange rule if I made an answer to the question that essentially says what is in the comment, along with some extra clarification on what I meant by that? People said they would love to award me a bounty for this comment, so turning it into an answer might come across as a (maybe even unethical) attempt at getting some quick rep.

Note: I would not just make an answer literally copying my comment. I would provide context as to why I turned it into an answer, summarize the answer the comment was on, then further explain ways to implement the comment. I know that Stack overflow and certainly Academia do not look kindly upon plagiarism, even if just self-plagiarism.

Comment: For the specific case on Academia.SE, I don't think you should make it an answer. The majority of your new answer would be copying the answer to which you commented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, sometimes great answers initially start out as comments. But, the answer must actually answer the *question*. It must not just be a sidenote (which your comment *is* at the moment, even if you would add some additional clarification).

Comment: See edit on how I would turn it into an answer. I wouldn't just post the comment as a literal answer.

Comment: @Nzall It would be no problem at all (plagiarism-wise) if you copy your own comment into an answer. The real problem will be giving it enough context to be a real answer *without* copying content/ideas from the answer you commented on.

Comment: Even with sourcing the answer I based it on? I see that happen all the time, answers that build on someone else's answer.

Comment: Yeah, maybe with the proper attribution that might work. I'm not familiar with the culture of Academics SE.

Comment: http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/71386/11593 I ended up going with this. do you think it's enough of an expansion to the original answer to be more than a sidenote?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it legit to turn a well-received comment I made on an answer into a separate answer?

This happens quite frequently, and even more frequently with regard to comments on a question. There have been a number of times where I have seen the OP comment on a comment to the question: "If you make that comment of yours an answer, I will accept it."

The above does not apply in this particular case. The comment you made was a sidebar. It did not answer the question. While it was a very well-received sidebar, it was still just a sidebar. Sidebars are not answers. They are just sidebars.

Answer (score 2):

The criterion, for the general case, is: does the comment answer the question? If it does, at least partially, then you can write it as an answer.

Glancing at the question and answer on Academia.SE, that comment does not seem to be an answer to the question. It is a comment on an answer, and only applicable to the procedure outlined in that particular answer.
So that comment should not be turned into an answer. At best, it might be edited into the answer to which it comments.

Comment: http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/71386/11593 do you think this adds enough information to avoid being "not an answer"?

Comment: @Nzall I think so. You also added that one could go to the university's administration instead of direclty contacting the researchers, which adds something new. From here on, it's up to the Academia.SE community.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, please.

Comments are only meant to get clarification or point out things for the OP. They are not meant to be ever lasting and fore all moderated contributions.

Users that leave a comment that almost is an answer often do so because they lack the time to write a proper answer at that moment, need to flesh other details before they can answer or to help others write an answer based on all the comments already present.

It is always preferable to have an answer because that answer can be edited, voted on and accepted by the OP. If you use comments from others to write an answer, don't forget to give attribution and maybe mark your answer Community Wiki